# Erro do tipo parsererror ao efetuar uma requisição AJAX crossDomain

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-service, cross-domain

Criei essa página para testar uma requisição ***cross domain*** com *AJAX*:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Services/WebServerStatus.asmx/TestConnection",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: { key: "querty" },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('good');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No script eu uso `dataType: "jsonp"` porque li por ai que ele é necessário para isso e não consegui com apenas `dataType: "json"`.
Com ambos, *"**jsonp**"* ou *"**json**"*, consigo parar o processo com um *break-point* ao *debugar* o serviço. Mas com *"**json**"* recebo a mesangem de erro *"**error**"* e *"**jsonp**"* é *"**parsererror**"*.

**Como posso resolver isso?**

Meu WebMethod:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void TestConnection(string key)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(new { 
        OnLine = true, 
        Message = "Requisição efetuada com sucesso!" 
    });
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

---

## EDIÇÃO

Pelo *Postman*, plugin do *Google Chrome* para efetuar requisições, usando a opção *"**form-data**"* para efetuar o pedido com o método post, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Formato de solicitação inválido: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygLlKC2yNIYzbStBM.
>      em System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>      em System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Mas, mudando para *"**x-www-form-urlencoded**"* eu já consigo realizar a requisição e receber o meu objeto ***json*** pelo *Postman*.

**Então, o que preciso mudar em meu script?**

Answer (score 1):

O Postman deve tratar essa questão sozinho, mas eu precisei mudar um pouco o meu WebMethod para então conseguir tratar o retorno.

Conforme resppsta aceita nessa **[questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697781/jquery-ajax-parsererror-processing-json)** no *SOen*, o retorno do tipo jsonp é esperado de forma que o resultado json esteja encapsulado em um método que trata o retorno.

O retorno deve ser algo do tipo `callback({....});`.

Logo, alterei meu WebMethod para isso:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void TestConnection(string key)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(new { 
        OnLine = true, 
        Message = "Requisição efetuada com sucesso!" 
    });
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";    
    Context.Response.Flush();

    var callback = Context.Request.QueryString["callback"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
        Context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1});", callback, json));
    else
        Context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Pronto, com isso minha requisição conseguiu tratar o retorno e o processo foi efetuado com sucesso.